# Handle Event in multi layer Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I used 3 layer to draw graphics: 2 layer by canvas and 1 by SVG.
 1 canvas will be render real-time to update graphic and i want to handle mouse event in SVG layer. 
But i can't catch any mouse event because the canvas catched all event.
I tried to set z-index for 2 canvas and svg . But it didn't work.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Without seeing some code, we're going to struggle to help here!

Comment: LOC is so long. I want to ask some common ideas to handle event with multi layer.

Comment: Not asking for the whole code, but some of it would be useful.